# Cannot implicitly convert Generic List to Generic List

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I am developing an application with `Blazor WebAssemply` and I got this error, they are the same List, but I still encounter this error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CTIControlCRUD.Data.CTIControl>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CTIControlCRUD.Pages.CTIControl>

On my **component**

```
 List<CTIControl> objCtiControl;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        objCtiControl = await Task.Run(()=> objCtiControlService.GetCTIControl());
    }
```

This is from the **service**

```
        public List<CTIControl> GetCTIControl()
        {
            var emplist = _db.CTIControls.ToList();
            return emplist;
        }
```

Comment: Probably the `_db.CTIControls.ToList();` returns a `CTIControlCRUD.Data.CTIControl` list but in your component you have  a `CTIControlCRUD.Pages.CTIControl` list. Check your namespaces. I would also advise you to use `void OnInitialized` instead of creating an async task...

Comment: This one is in Pages: objCtiControl = await Task.Run(()=> objCtiControlService.GetCTIControl()); that calls the service in Data: var emplist = _db.CTIControls.ToList();. namespaces are correct, I still cant understand why the error occured

Comment: `CTIControlCRUD.Data.CTIControl` seems to be different that `CTIControlCRUD.Pages.CTIControl`

Comment: ```@page "/cticontrol"
@using CTIControlCRUD.Data
@inject CTIControlService objCtiControlService```    -this is declared on the Pages, so I can call the getCtiControl from the Data

Comment: @LeoAngeloTrinidadDacullo Implement a common interface then and make a list of that.